# press ESC without selection a element selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, popup, element

i´m trying to get into selenium. If i try to get on the website [www.snipes.com](http://www.snipes.com) a region select pop up pops up. I can´t find the element to close this but if i press ESC this pop up closes itself. Is there any way to press the ESC key without select an element first? If not, whats the className of the "x" or what element can i use to close it with the ESC key?

```
//to close the pop up with the "x"
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
        
            //Snipes Region
            driver.get("https://www.snipes.com/login");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            selectRegion = driver.findElementByClassName("js-close-btn a-modal-close-button close");
            selectRegion.click();
```

[html code, cant find the className](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MduQ0.jpg)

[the pop up im trying to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov9Yy.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below xpath to click the close button:

```
"//*[@class='i-close-thin']"
```

Also you can send escape to the body element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

Comment: Thank, but now i have to problem that sometimes the Element can be found but most of the time not. Is there no way that the Key ESCAPE can be send without an element?

Comment: Just add explicit wait for body to be available